# como obtengo los valores seleccionados

Tags: javascript

tengo 3 tipos de formularios, cada uno de ellos con varios inputs

```
$("#formulario1, #formulario2, #formulario3 ").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var arreglo=[];
            $this.each(function () {
                arreglo.push($(this).val());
            });
```

pero como obtengo los `inputs` del formulario que quiero enviar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede usar JQuery para validar el form

```
var arreglo=new Array();
$("#formulario1, #formulario2, #formulario3 ").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

if($(this).attr("id")=="formulario1"){
    $(this).find("input").each(function(){
        arreglo.push($(this).val());
    });
}else if(){
...
}
...
```

Saludos :)